# Sorting by Elements in Collection in Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on an application using Neo4J and I'm having problems with the sorting in some of the queries. I have a list of stores that have promotions so I have a node for each store and a node for each promotion. Each store can have multiple promotions so it's a one to many relationship. Some of the promotions are featured (featured property = true) so I want those to appear first. I'm trying to construct a query that does the following:

- Returns a list of stores with the promotoions as a collection (returning it like this is ideal for paging)
- Sorts the stores so the ones with most featured promotions appear first
- Sorts the collection so that the promotions that are featured appear first

So far I have the following:

`MATCH (p:Promotion)-[r:BELONGS_TO_STORE]->(s:Store) WITH p, s, collect(p.featured) as featuredCol WITH p, s, LENGTH(FILTER(i IN featuredCol where i='true')) as featuredCount ORDER BY p.featured DESC, featuredCount DESC RETURN s, collect(p) skip 0 limit 10`

First, I try to create a collection using the featured property using a WITH clause. Then, I try to create a second collection where the featured property is equal to true and then get the length in a second WITH clause. This sorts the collection with the promotions correctly but not the stores. I get an error if I try to add another sort at the end like this because the featuredCount variable is not in the RETURN clause. I don't want the featuredCount variable in the RETURN clause because it throws my pagination off.

Here is my second query:

`MATCH (p:Promotion)-[r:BELONGS_TO_STORE]->(s:Store) WITH p, s, collect(p.featured) as featuredCol WITH p, s, LENGTH(FILTER(i IN featuredCol where i='true')) as featuredCount ORDER BY p.featured DESC, featuredCount DESC RETURN s, collect(p) ORDER BY featuredCount skip 0 limit 10`

I'm very new to Neo4J so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this query ([see this console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=cq6y3e)) work for you?

```
MATCH (p:Promotion)-[r:BELONGS_TO_STORE]->(s:Store)
WITH p, s
ORDER BY p.featured DESC 
WITH s, COLLECT(p) AS pColl
WITH s, pColl, REDUCE(n = 0, p IN pColl | CASE
                      WHEN p.featured
                      THEN n + 1
                      ELSE n END ) AS featuredCount
ORDER BY featuredCount DESC 
RETURN s, pColl
LIMIT 10
```

This query performs the following steps:

- It orders the matched rows so that the rows with featured promotions are first.
- It aggregates all the `p` nodes for each distinct `s` into a `pColl` collection. The featured promotions still appear first within each `pColl`.
- It calculates the number of featured promotions in each `pColl`, and orders the stores so that the ones with the most features promotions appear first.
- It then returns the results.

Note: This query assumes that `featured` has a boolean value, not a string. (FYI: `ORDER BY` considers `true` to be greater than `false`). If this assumption is not correct, you can change the `WHEN` clause to `WHEN p.featured = 'true'`.